# Informing user about the progress of sql procedure execution in MS Access

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In my application I have SQL Server 2008 in the backend and MS Access 2010 in the front end. I have long running procedures that are executed through MS Access. For example now I need to show a messege box in the MS ACCESS front end to the user when the SQL procedure is currently running. Please provide me an idea how can I accomplish that... Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you running the procedures? By executing a Pass-Through query? In any case, you won't be able to show progress, only that the procedure is still running.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use MS-Access in asynchronous calls - even if you had a way to set a file-based counter from your stored procedure - you wouldn't be able to track it from inside Access while the stored procedure is running.

The only two ways I see that could do something like this is to

- change your stored procedure to handle some kind of paging counter -
  using a loop in VBA, and passing, tracking and incrementing a first
  pointer and last pointer to your stored procedure - then reporting on
  progress, or,
- find a way to shell-nowait out to call the stored procedure and then
  monitor and report on the progress in VBA

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! Between I have solved it in another way. I open a new form before the procedures start running which informs the user that the procedure is running and I am closing the form again after all the procedures ran.